# Passing information between JavaScript methods

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have an object with two different sets of objects inside:

```
var myObj;
(function (myObj) {
    var myFunction = (function () {
        function myFunction(){
           this.myValue = "something";
        }
        myFunction.getValue = function () {
           var _this = this;

           return _this.myValue;
        }
        return myFunction;
    })();
    myObj.myFunction = myFunction;

    var myFunction2 = (function () {
        function myFunction2() {
        }
        myFunction2.prototype.something = function () {
            var a = myFunction.getValue();
        }
        return myFunction2;
    })();
    myObj.myFunction2 = myFunction2;        
})(myObj || (myObj = {}));
```

Every time I run `myFunction2.something()`, `a` is assigned: `undefined`.

How can I get the value from `myFunction` into `myFunction2.something()`?

Comment: I don't know if it's just because it's late where I am (02:20am UK time) but this question and the code example you've given is confusing me. What's with all the self-calling methods? There **must** be a simpler way to achieve whatever the heck it is you're trying to do...

Comment: I assume this is just a typo in your question, but shouldn't `var a = myfunction.getValue();` be `var a = myFunction.getValue();`? (You missed the camelCase in `myFunction`.)

Comment: @Jared fixed it, thanks

Comment: @TomDyer It's for a customized field for a CMS -- I'm building out a namespace hierarchy in case more people have to build off of it.  The CMS is rather unyeildly (SharePoint). I changed the code, from what I actually have, but this is the gist of it.  The way it calls functions when it loads them is why they have to be selfloading

Comment: a is assigned: `unassigned`? Should be `undefined`? Running `myFunction2.something()` should get error `myFunction2.something is not a function`

Comment: I think you mean `undefined`, not `unassigned`, but the reason is quite simple: there is no `myFunction.myValue` property. `myValue` is a *local variable* that will exists only when and only as long as the `myFunction` function is called. Since it doesn't return the value, there is no way to access it.

Comment: Can you create a simple jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Whoa, stay clear of those IEFEs. They seem to be pretty overused in your example, complicating everything even more. Btw, to only call that function correctly, you have to do `(new myObj.myFunction2()).something()` - for some reason, you created `something` as a prototype method.

Comment: @Bergi something() is definitely being called, I'm not worried about that. I am able to step through it in chrome. It calls the myFunction.getValue() and inside that call myValue is undefined.  You're saying that's expected because it's a local variable?

Comment: @Snowburnt: Yeah, it might be called, but not by the expression you've shown us - `myFunction2.something()` definitively doesn't work, it would be nice if you could provide the code you're stepping through. Yes, I say that the `undefined` result is expected.

Comment: @Bergi if I moved myValue to myObj, would that make it visible to both?  I can't really make a fiddle, my code only runs in SharePoint, the only instance I have available is on my VM.

Comment: Yeah, you either need to move the variable declaration in a scope that is visible to where you want to access it (and remove the `this.`), or you need to make it a property (of whatever object you see fitting) and access that appropriately

Comment: @Bergi That definitely fixed it, though I do have a lot of refactoring ahead of me from the looks of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is quite a mixup of scopes and design patterns in your code. Having 2 functions named the same way on inside the other creates different scopes for that name depending on where you call them. This quickly gets out of control. Like in this part:

```
var myFunction = (function () {  // this guy is named myFunction
    function myFunction(){ // this guy is also named myFunction
       this.myValue = "something"; // 'this' here most certainly refers to 'window', not myFunction. Unless you do a 'new myFunction()' a la prototype
    }
    myFunction.getValue = function () {
       var _this = this;// same here

       return _this.myValue;
    }
    return myFunction;// here you are returning a function, not an object with methods
})();
```

Also I noticed that you are handling some logic with prototypes and other with closures, this also is kinda confusing when someone else (or you in a couple of months) need to refactor this code.

```
   myFunction.getValue = function () {
       var _this = this;

       return _this.myValue;
    }
    return myFunction;
```

You could go all prototypes or all closures. I prefer closures so here is what I would do.

```
var myObj;
(function (myObj) {
    // in this closure, we create a scope and return only the public methods
    var myFunction = (function () {
        // define properties here
        var myValue = 'default value';

        // define your methods, here we return
        // myValue declared on the parent scope
        function getValue() {
           return myValue;
        }

        // this acts as a constructor, it autoexecutes
        (function init(){
           myValue = "something";
        })();

        // return all the functions in this scope
        // you want to expose
        return {
            getValue: getValue
        };
    })();
    // we then put myFunction into myObj
    // at this point myFunction is an object with a method called getValue()
    myObj.myFunction = myFunction;

    var myFunction2 = (function () {
        function something() {
            // once this guy is called, we get the value from the other 'class'
            var a = myFunction.getValue();
            alert(a);// voila!
        }

        (function myFunction2() {
            // do your init stuff here
        })();
        return {
            something: something
        };
    })();
    myObj.myFunction2 = myFunction2;        
})(myObj || (myObj = {}));

// at this point myObj is an object with 2 'classes', each 'class' has its own methods
// we can proceed and call the desired method
myObj.myFunction2.something();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bzw9kse7/

Comment: "*`// this acts as a constructor, it autoexecutes`*" - WTH? You already *are* inside an IIFE

Comment: yeah but it helps keeping your code organized and helps people who come from a OOP background understand closures, no need to get angry mate

Comment: Wonderfully simplified, this was really beneficial to helping me to understand this sort of coding pattern.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Sorry, got this all wrong. It returns `undefined` because getValue is a static method of myFunction Object, not an instance method. That means that the `this` is not the same as in myFunction constructor.

Moreover you are not even attaching myValue to the `this` anywhere...

**Edit 2** I added getMyValue to the myFunction prototype.

Try this:

```
    ....

    var myFunction = (function () {
            function myFunction(){
               this.myValue = "something";
            }
            myFunction.prototype.getValue = function () {
               return this.myValue;
            }

            // this creates the instance of the myFunction class. 
            return new myFunction();
        })();
        myObj.myFunction = myFunction;

       ...

       // now you should be able to see the right result
       var a = myFunction.getValue();
```

---

This is one of the craziest code I have ever seen, but the answer is this:

`var a = myFunction.getValue();` is `undefined` because your 2nd definition of myFunction returns undefined, as in here:

```
function myFunction(){
           var myValue = "something";
        }
```

Your 2nd definition of myFunction actually replaces the 1st. See the comments below:

```
var myFunction = (function () {

        // this definition replaces the one above
        function myFunction(){
           var myValue = "something";
        }
        myFunction.getValue = function () {
           var _this = this;

           return _this.myValue;
        }

        // which makes this return to not be taking in account when you are 
        // calling myFunction()
        return myFunction;
    })();
```

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped, myFunction() should be this.myValue = "something";

Comment: The real problem was that you never instantiated the myFunction class.

Answer (score 0):

I've stepped through your code and just noticed a couple small things you're doing wrong.

You appear to be misdefining myFunction slightly, because it's not going to have myValue as a member variable, just a temporary variable that quickly falls out of scope. (And because it becomes undefined, it gets assigned to a, which is then unassigned).

So, replace these lines:

```
var myFunction = (function () {
    function myFunction(){
        var myValue = "something";
    }
    myFunction.getValue = function () {
        var _this = this;
        return _this.myValue;
    }
    return myFunction;
})();
```

With this:

```
var myFunction = (function () {
    var myFunction = {};
    myFunction.myValue = "something";
    myFunction.getValue = function () {
       var _this = this;

       return _this.myValue;
    }
    return myFunction;
})();
```

Comment: As suggested in some other comments, it's worth noting that the first definition of myFunction and the second definition of myFunction should definitely be named different things for clarity's sake.

Comment: They're not actually named that in the code...this is just a snippet to demonstrate my problem, the actual code is much longer.